# Issue retrieving XML data from logic apps

Tags: xml, xpath, azure-logic-apps

I'm working to process a series of XML files located in Azure blobs using Logic Apps. I'm having an issue retrieving the contents of an XML node. My XML is:

```
<Provider xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" MyID="805" MySecondID="027" MyDate="2020-08-11T09:33:35" ID="1000" xmlns="urn:GeoAccess.PDE.Provider">
  <LastName>PersonalName</LastName>
  <FirstName>NotPersonalName</FirstName>
</Provider>
```

When I try the XPath tester at: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html, this expression works properly:

```
/Provider/LastName/text()
```

When I try this in the logic app using:

```
@xpath(xml(body('Get_blob_content')), '/Provider/LastName/text()')
```

I get an empty string returned.

What should I try instead ?

Comment: The XML in question has a default namespace, `xmlns="urn:GeoAccess.PDE.Provider"`. You need to take it into account.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. Solved it in Logic Apps using the xpath:


/*[local-name()=\"Provider\" and namespace-uri()=\"urn:GeoAccess.PDE.Provider\"]/*[local-name()=\"LastName\"]/text()

Comment: @Rajesh I post an answer to end this question.If you would like to post an answer,I will delete it.Thanks.

Comment: @SteveZhao Turns out while this xpath expression does give a result, when I use it as a dynamic expression in Logic apps, I get a JSON array with one element that is a string. The string is correct, but I would like to remove the JSON array returned. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

The question cause by default namespace,`xmlns="urn:GeoAccess.PDE.Provider"`.You need to
take it into account.

Solved it in Logic Apps using the xpath:

> /*[local-name()="Provider" and
> namespace-uri()="urn:GeoAccess.PDE.Provider"]/*[local-name()="LastName"]/text()